# How to map values in single column of a dataframe to two columns of another dataframe and extract the mapped values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("data1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("data2.xlsx"

df1

Data1   Data2   Score
ABC      AB1    1
AB1      ABC    4
AB2      AB2    6
ABC      ABD    0.7
GDH      ABD    0.9
KMN      KSF    0.5
KSF      KSF    6

df2

Data1
AB1
AB2
ABC
```

I want to map `df2["Data1"]` to `df1` and extract the mapping values:

```
merged_data = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner', left_on='Data1', right_on='Data1')
merged_data2 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner', left_on='Data1', right_on='Data2')

combined_data = pd.concat([merged_data,merged_data2])
#remove duplicates
combined_data_rm = combined_data.drop_duplicates()
combined_data_rm

Data1   Data2   Score
ABC      AB1    1
AB1      ABC    4
AB2      AB2    6
ABC      ABD    0.7
```

Is there any alternate way of doing with analysis using pandas?

Comment: will `inner` join work?

Comment: `inner` will not give the output you have mentioned

Comment: ```df = df1[df1['Data1'].isin(df2['Data1']) | df1['Data2'].isin(df2['Data1'])]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["Data1"]))
```

O/P:

```
  Data1 Data2  Score
0   ABC   AB1    1.0
1   ABC   ABD    0.7
2   AB1   ABC    4.0
3   AB2   AB2    6.0
```

Comment: say suppose I have different header name in the data frame. Will this work using `left_on` and `right_on`

Comment: yes, it will work.

Comment: it will not work as you expected. Try and see @svp

Comment: @user288925- why it won't work? If you have any solution for OP, please post your answer as a separate thread.